# How do you style an overlap in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm coding a website and I'm trying to overlap a line on the page so that it looks better on my site. This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to style it to overlap? The code is:

```
borderstyleone:{
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    height: 600,
    width: 1,
    marginBottom: -610,
    marginRight: 140,
    bottom: 440,
    right: 530,

    
    


  },
```

Comment: Could you specify exactly what you need? Are you trying to have your nav tab icons to the left?

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I just want to overlap the bar under signup so that it looks better